# Representing a Django model that holds permutations of ForeignKeys

Tags: database, django

I'm working on a project in Django for blind testing, and I would like to know about best practices for database structure.

Here is a simplified version of my code to demonstrate the issue I'm having:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Test(models.Model):
    product_a = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='a_products')
    product_b = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='b_products')

class Trial(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)

    # Is there a more elegant way to represent the fact that these three
    # variables are all a permutation of test.product_a and test.product_b?
    order_1 = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orders_1')
    order_2 = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orders_2')
    order_3 = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orders_3')
```

My models are roughly set up like this. There are many `Trials` for a single `Test`. A `Trial` needs to hold a three-element permutation of its `test.product_a` and `test.product_b`. The way I have it set up now doesn't capture that at all, and it just seems really inelegant. I've considered mapping integers to permutations, and storing the integer corresponding to the permutation, but that doesn't seem great either. I don't know much about databases at all, so I would love to hear a better way to structure this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need trial to hold three product references in any combination of its test's two products?  I think your model definitions are fine, but I would use `Trial.clean()` to validate that each of (order_1, order_2, order_3) are one of (product_a, product_b):

```
def clean(self):
  super(Trial, self).clean()
  for order in (order_1, order_2, order_3):
    if order not in (self.test.product_a, self.test.product_b):
      raise ValidationError("Order not one of test's products.")
```

Now, unless there is a difference in the relationship between a test and its product_a and the relationship between that test and its product_b, I think that should really be a many to many.  The same goes for the Trial-Product relationship.  You can validate that values being set fit your criteria.  You could go with something like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
  products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='tests')
  def clean(self):
    super(Test, self).clean()
    if self.products.all().count() != 2:
      raise ValidationError('Test should have 2 products')

class Trial(models.Model):
  test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
  orders = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='trials')
  def clean(self):
    super(Trial, self).clean()
    if self.orders.all().count() != 3:
      raise ValidationError('Trial should have 3 orders')
    for product in self.orders.all():
      if product not in self.test.products.all():
        raise ValidationError("Order not one of test's products")
```

I've changed your related_names, too. They are used for the reverse relationship, so to get Trials and Tests related to a given Product you'd use:

```
product = //some Product
trials = product.trials.all()
tests = product.tests.all()
```